# Android App crashing on Android 12+ Devices on background in push notifications, Application compiled from Cordova

Tags: android, vue.js, cordova, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-FCMService
Process: com.petbacker.android, PID: 4405
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.petbacker.android: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:401)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:484)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:470)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:434)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzf(Unknown Source:68)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc.zzas(Unknown Source:34)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source:59)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.run(Unknown Source:2)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:6)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

App Should not crash on push Notifications in background

Answer (score 1):

This Might help you,

Add this in FirebaseService class

```
                try {
                    //ToDo Update the code for S+
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                                (this, 101, intent,
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE| PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                                (this, 101, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT| PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Not able to see PendingIntent  class or library, where to add in the project ?